# Java Eclipse, how to make Windowbuilder show all Panels after execution?

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I am working with WindowBuilder at the moment but have a problem making it display all panels in the program in the "Components" Window. I have a "StartPanel" for example with a button which when clicked causes the program to switch from "startPanel" to "nextPanel". Everything fine but in this case, "nextPanel" isnt shown in the "components" window, why?

When I however copy all the code which creates the "nextPanel" and write it outside of the "ActionListener" so that I do not have to click a button to create it, it appears in the "components" window. Is there a way to make every panel appear in "Components"? At the moment I have a frame with a getContentPane which has the 2 Panels in it, but only 1 is shown if I add the second one with a button..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create the next panel as a separate component (separate class file) so that you can edit it using window builder any time, and then instantiate it in the action listener.

Comment: You mean for each panel a new class? Is that really efficient? Im pretty new to GUI's in Java and at the moment I create every Panel right when its really needed, so Buttonclick for example causes new panel to be created and then switch with the old one. Is each panel a new class the way to go? That would be alot of classes..

Comment: To have separate classes will make no difference in terms of CPU or memory efficiency. That would be efficient in terms of coding by being reusable, extensible and easy to maintain and test.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks alot for the answer! Thats the way I will be doing it then!